# WordPress testing error: use of undefined constant

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing

I sm working with a windows OS created wordpress plugin unit testing code written as below

```
<?php

class Test_WP_Simple_Plugin extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function test_constants () {
        $this->assertSame( 'wp-simple-plugin', WPSP_NAME );  //Error line

        $url = str_replace( 'tests/phpunit/tests/', '',
                trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) );
        $this->assertSame( $url, WPSP_URL );
    }
}
```

that gives an error message

Use of undefined constant WPSP_NAME - assumed 'WPSP_NAME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

please help what is wrong in this code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably, that the WPSP_NAME variable has not been declared.